# I have 4 laravel projects, i want to use 1 storage in all project to view files?

Tags: php, laravel, file, storage

I have 4 laravel projects, on admin side i am uploading pictures for users and picture, other downloadable files for students. I want one storage for all projects so all users can download files, upload files, etc.

I am only using public/uploads folder to upload files and retrive files from this folder on admin side only.

Comment: use something like S3

Comment: S3 is for amazon right? but i wantr to use my own storage in laravel project. But i also have 100TB google drive as well, is it possible to use Gdrive to upload and download or view files form there

Comment: yeah, any centralized storage works, even connecting your projects via a shared volume if your hosting service allows it. Is the database shared between these projects?

Comment: yes db is same for 4 projects

Comment: i have cpanel hosting

Comment: when you upload a file you can store the path and domain of the file on the db, and each server can look up on the db from what server the file should be served based on the saved domain.

Comment: If  you are going to change the assets directory of **all** project (e.g. project/public/xx to /var/www/somewhere), you also need to change the configuration of all projects to match the new assets directory plus update the permission of said directory.

Comment: Or the easiest is to dockerize a minio. Minio uses the same s3 api.